# How to change name attributes for auto added inputs and textareas?

Tags: html, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to create a cv creater form and need to let users add more inputs (auto).

I created inputs and they work just fine, but I need to change the name attribute for each auto added block.

For example :

```
<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">
<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname2">
<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname3">
```

I know I can use `name="value[]"` array, but every new block goes into a different column in the  database, so I need to change attributes.

My code :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields = 10;
    var wrapper = $("#contant");
    var add_button = $("#add_form_field");

    var x = 1;
    $(add_button).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (x < max_fields) {
            x++;
            $(wrapper).append('<div id="input-social" class="input-container"><input type="text" id="social" class="col-11 form-control" name="fname" placeholder="fname"> <span id="deleteInput" class="AutoInput" title="Delete"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></span></div>');
        } else {
            alert('You Riched limit.')
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click", "#deleteInput", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('#input-social').remove();
        x--;
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e794a0f8b4.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <label class="col-3 inputFontSize" for="social">Others</label>
        <div id="contant" class="col-7">
        <button id="add_form_field" class="btn add_form_field">Add more &nbsp; <i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
     </div>
    <!-- col-9 -->
    
    </div>
    <!-- row --> 
</div>
<!-- form-group -->
```

Thanks for all helps

Comment: Not hard to use the same index of each array name to do your db entires

Comment: @charlietfl would you give an example please ? I dont get what you mean.

Comment: When you use `[]` names....they are received as arrays server side. So `firstname[2]` would be paired with `lastname[2]` for db processing of a row

Comment: @charlietfl I think you meant this right ? `http://localhost/html/Array ( [0] => test text [1] => test text [2] => test text )` each input get a uniqe id in array so, I wouldnt know which lastname is belong to first name. but I know what you mean. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your `x` variable that is incremented for each added `input` and append it to the `name` attribute. We'll use a 'template string'. The adjustment is `name="fname${x}"` which will substitute `${x}` for the value of `x`.

```js
$(wrapper).append(`
  <div id="input-social" class="input-container">
    <input type="text" id="social" class="col-11 form-control" name="fname${x}" placeholder="fname">
    <span id="deleteInput" class="AutoInput" title="Delete">
      <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
    </span>
  </div>`
);
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields = 10;
    var wrapper = $("#contant");
    var add_button = $("#add_form_field");

    var x = 1;
    $(add_button).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (x < max_fields) {
            x++;
            $(wrapper).append(`<div id="input-social" class="input-container"><input type="text" id="social" class="col-11 form-control" name="fname${x}" placeholder="fname"> <span id="deleteInput" class="AutoInput" title="Delete"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></span></div>`);
        } else {
            alert('You Riched limit.')
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click", "#deleteInput", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('#input-social').remove();
        x--;
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e794a0f8b4.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <label class="col-3 inputFontSize" for="social">Others</label>
        <div id="contant" class="col-7">
        <button id="add_form_field" class="btn add_form_field">Add more &nbsp; <i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
     </div>
    <!-- col-9 -->
    
    </div>
    <!-- row --> 
</div>
<!-- form-group -->
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer, I tried that before this is the result  `<input type="text" id="social" class="col-11 form-control" name="fname${x}" placeholder="fname">` it doesnt include numbers, that counter counts added inputs.

Comment: Seems to be working for me. I've added a snippet, give it a run and inspect the added fields - they have unique `name` attributes. Make sure you're changing the appended html from a regular string to a template string otherwise `${x}` wont work.